# Cayley table for 2-bit integers ${Z_4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cryptography

Let us consider the multiplication operation, denoted by $ \odot $ on the set of 2-bit integers ${Z_4}$ defined as follows:

$$\eqalign{
  & a \odot b = (ab\,\bmod \,5)\,\bmod \,4\,if\,a \ne 0,\,b \ne 0  \cr 
  & 0 \odot a = a \odot 0 = (4a\,\bmod \,5)\,\bmod \,4  \cr 
  & 0 \odot 0 = 1 \cr} $$

**The task is**

1. Compute the Cayley table for $ \odot $
2. Show that $({Z_4}, \odot )$ is isomorphic with multiplicative group of the field ${Z_5}$

For the first part i have constructed the Cayley table. Is it correct?

\begin{array}{ccc}
 \odot & \textbf{0} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\
 \textbf{0} & 1 & 0 & 3 & 2 & & \\ 
\textbf{1} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & & \\
\textbf{2} & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & & \\
\textbf{3} & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & &  
\end{array}

How can i show that ${Z_4}$ is isomorphic with multiplicative group of the field ${Z_5}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your multiplication table is correct. As for showing that your group is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_5$, note that the multiplication table is given by

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 3 \\
3 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 2 \\
4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{array}

Note how similar this is to your multiplication table. You want a function to map $\{0,1,2,3\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that your multiplication table looks like mine. Isomorphic groups have identical multiplication tables (modulo "naming" of variables and rearranging of rows/columns accordingly). This is, in fact, why we call them isomorphic groups - up to naming, we can't really distinguish them apart since they have the same action. Hint: notice that $1\odot a = a = a\odot 1$ in your group and look at the diagonals in our multiplication tables - these will give you a couple of good ideas as to how to map things.

Comment: I'm stuck with finding a function that would allow to map $\{ 0,1,2,3\} $ to $\{ 1,2,3,4\} $. Clearly we can notice that $1 \odot a = a = a \odot 1$ so it means that 1 is an identity for both tables. What i have noticed that in both tables the operation $a \odot b = a - 1$ if $a < b,\,\,\,\,a \ne 1$ and $a \odot b = b - 1$ if $a > b,\,\,\,a \ne 1$.

Comment: As for diagonals comparison: 
What function can map $1 \to 1,\,\,\,1 \to 4,\,\,\,0 \to 4,\,\,\,0 \to 1$?

Comment: Here's a further hint: rewrite your table so that $1$ is in the first row and first column in place of $0$.

Comment: Like this? $$\begin{array}{ccc}
 \odot & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} \\
\textbf{1} & 1 & 2 & 3 & & \\
\textbf{2} & 2 & 0 & 1 & & \\
\textbf{3} & 3 & 1 & 0 & &  
\end{array}$$

Comment: Well make sure $0$ is represented in there as well..

Comment: Like this? $$\begin{array}{ccc}  \odot & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{0} \\ \textbf{1} & 1 & 2 & 3  & 0 & \\ \textbf{2} & 2 & 0 & 1 & 3 & \\ \textbf{3} & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & \\ \textbf{0} & 0 & 3 & 2 & 1& \end{array}$$

Comment: Ok i got it now ))) $0 \to 4,\,\,\,1 \to 1,\,\,\,2 \to 2,\,\,\,3 \to 3$

Comment: Exactly right :)

Comment: You're very welcome